# How to perform IF statment on a 2D array stored char rather than the [posX] [posY] vaule

Tags: c, if-statement, multidimensional-array

Have a few if statements and I need them to be activated by a char's value stored in an array, not off the array's positional co-ordinate value.

Debugging has indicated I've failed to specify the array's char value.

In summary -- Code steps though fine and the else statement works. I just can't work out how to write the code to look for the stored char in the X & Y position so it can carry out the IF statement.

Currently is correctly skipping the IF statement.

```
void function(char source[SIZE_X][SIZE_Y], char input, int* posX, int* posY, int counter) {


    if (input == 'A') {
        printf("XXXX\n");

        if (source[*posX][*posY] == 'B') {
            printf("XXXX\n\n");
            (*posX) = *posX + 0;
        }
    
        else (*posX) = *posX + 1;
    }
```

Comment: Which `if` statement is it skipping over?

Comment: Why are `posX` and `posY` being passed by-pointer? How are their values being passed?

Comment: `source[*posX][*posY]` is testing the value stored in the array.

Comment: @Dai Notice that it increments `*posX`. So it needs to pass the pointer.

Comment: Sorry should have added it's skipping - IF (source[*posX][*posY] == 'B') {

Comment: It would only skip that if `input != 'A'`

Comment: Please post a [mcve] showing the contents of the array and the values of all the arguments.

Comment: So for all intents and purpose there looks to be some other issue in my code not the IF statement structure?

That's fine I can look outside the function.
I'd love to post more code but as it's for an assignment I'm not keen on getting in trouble and wasting weeks of effort. - still appreciate the help.

Comment: Code looks fine. However, this `(*posX) = *posX + 0;` does nothing.

Comment: `source[*posX][*posY] == 'B'` **is** checking the **value** stored at position `(*posX, *posY)`. It's very unclear what you are asking.

Comment: Ahh thanks that really does help. I will start to see what's not getting passed to the function correctly. 
(*posX) = *posX + 0; is just test code still working out the correct X and Y moment for the graphical interface that is the 2d Array. 

Do sincerely than you all for the help. Knowing this code is doing what I intended helps me work out what I've done wrong else where.

Comment: The only explanation is that there is no `'B'`  stored at that position. Add this before the `if`-statement: `printf("X=%d, Y=%d, value=%c\n", *posX, *posY, source[*posX][*posY]);` This will show you which position you are looking at and the value stored at that position.

Comment: suppose the array is source[5][6]. if 'B' is not found in source[0][0], the it will search for 'B' in source[1][0], then source[2][0],....,source[5][0],...,source[7][0]. So, it will only search for 'B' in first column. you should add some condition that it also search for 'B' in next columns too.

Comment: Hey Miraz, thanks for the advice but the codes been cut down so the context is lost. There are quite a few IF statements checking multiple chars to do multiple things. The arrays a graphical representation of a game board and if the piece hits that array location. The char that is present represents a obstacle or a win / loose condition. So I don't want to check if there are obstacles on each or any line. Well maybe if I wanted to cheat I guess? I should also mention it's working now. Only one more issue and it's done!